# What does the acronym DAO mean in the book Clean Code?

Tags: meaning, acronyms

I am reading a book called Clean Code. Although it is actually in Portuguese (translated) there  are some code samples which aren't translated, so I don't know the meaning of the acronym "DAO" (`Meal expenses = expenseReportDAO.getMeals(employee.getID());`)

Maybe it can be explained by the context. Here's where it is mentioned:

> Define the Normal Flow
>
> Look at an example
>
> ```
> try {
>     MealExpenses expenses = expenseReportDAO.getMeals(employee.getID());
>     m_total += expenses.getTotal();
> } catch(MealExpensesNotFound e) {
>     m_total += getMealPerDiem();
> }
> ```
>
> In this business, if meals are expensed, they become part of the total. If they aren't, the employee gets a meal per diem amount for that day. The exception clutters the logic.
>
> Our code would look much simpler, if:
>
> ```
> public class PerDiemMealExpenses implements MealExpenses {
>     public int getTotal() {
>         // return the per diem default
>     }
> }
> ...
> MealExpenses expenses = expenseReportDAO.getMeals(employee.getID());
> m_total += expenses.getTotal();
> ```
>
> This is called the SPECIAL CASE PATTERN. You create a class or configure an object so that it handles a special case for you

Comment: Acronym (cf NATO) or initialism (cf BBC)? // [Acronym Finder](https://www.acronymfinder.com/DAO.html) lists about 50 possible expansions, starting with 'Data Access Objects (Microsoft)' but I can't find one that obviously makes sense here. Possibly better asked on Computer Science.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be on https://cseducators.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Greybeard I didn't know that acronym is about computer science until they answer me, and it is still a question about english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In software, DAO normally is used as an abbreviation for [***data access object***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) [(em português)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objeto_de_acesso_a_dados). Quoting the English Wikipedia,

> In software, a data access object (DAO) is a pattern that provides an abstract interface to some type of database or other persistence mechanism. By mapping application calls to the persistence layer, the DAO provides some specific data operations without exposing details of the database. This isolation supports the single responsibility principle. It separates what data access the application needs, in terms of domain-specific objects and data types (the public interface of the DAO), from how these needs can be satisfied with a specific DBMS, database schema, etc. (the implementation of the DAO).
>
> Although this design pattern is equally applicable to most programming languages, most types of software with persistence needs, and most types of databases, it is traditionally associated with Java EE applications and with relational databases (accessed via the JDBC API because of its origin in Sun Microsystems' best practice guidelines[1] "Core J2EE Patterns" for that platform).